# c# How to receive Fax using FAXCOMEXLIB

Tags: c#, fax

I'm trying to receive faxes using Faxcomexlib and save them as a tiff file (.tiff), but finding very little documentation on how to achieve this using c#.

I have a fax modem connected to my machine and can send faxes using my application but can't seem to find out how to receive any a incoming fax.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: All fax samples are written in vb, translating to C# is mechanical since the interface, method and property names are the same.  Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx